# I'm getting the value off "undefined" inside of getting the value off my textbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to be able to write something inside off my text box and then get the value off it added to my objects that i have pushed into a list "let myToDos = [];"

```js
window.onload = function(){

    // without this my site keeps realoding when adding a new item
    let firstTask = new Todo ('Bädda sängen');
    let secondTask = new Todo ('Hänga upp tavlorna');
    let thirdTask = new Todo ('Kick back & realx');

    // Adding my premade todo's into my Array that has the variable 'myToDos'
    myToDos.push(firstTask);
    myToDos.push(secondTask);
    myToDos.push(thirdTask);

    // creating a function so that the user can add a new todo
    let addButton = document.getElementById('addBtn');
    addButton.addEventListener('click',addNewTask);

    preMadeTasks ();
    

    console.log(myToDos);
}

let myToDos = [];

    class Todo{
        constructor(toDoItem){
            this.toDoItem = toDoItem;
        }
    }


function addNewTask (e){

    e.preventDefault();
    let test = document.getElementById ("mySection");
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    
    if (inputValue == ""){
        alert("Type in something");
    }[enter image description here][1]
    else{
        myToDos.push(inputValue);
        test.innerHTML="";
        preMadeTasks();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `addNewTask` function you are pushing a string value into the `myToDos` array instead of an instance of the `Todo` class. You have to do:
`myToDos.push(new Todo(inputValue));`

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i wanted :)